# flask_ask won't import after proper installation

Tags: python, pi-4, python-3, software-installation, alexa

I'm trying to use the flask_ask library however I for some reason can't get it to work. Whenever I try to reinstall flask-ask by doing pip install flask-ask I am given the same thing below so I think I have it installed.

```
 Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Requirement already satisfied: flask-ask in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (0.9.8)
Requirement already satisfied: Flask==0.12.1 in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from flask-ask) (0.12.1)
Requirement already satisfied: aniso8601==1.2.0 in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from flask-ask) (1.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyOpenSSL==17.0.0 in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from flask-ask) (17.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six==1.11.0 in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from flask-ask) (1.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied: PyYAML==3.12 in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from flask-ask) (3.12)
Requirement already satisfied: click>=2.0 in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from Flask==0.12.1->flask-ask) (7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: Werkzeug>=0.7 in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from Flask==0.12.1->flask-ask) (0.14.1)
Requirement already satisfied: Jinja2>=2.4 in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from Flask==0.12.1->flask-ask) (2.10)
Requirement already satisfied: itsdangerous>=0.21 in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from Flask==0.12.1->flask-ask) (0.24)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from aniso8601==1.2.0->flask-ask) (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: cryptography>=1.7 in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from pyOpenSSL==17.0.0->flask-ask) (2.6.1)
```

Then when I go back to try to run it in Python 3.7.3 it simply says that the flask-ask library doesn't exist.
[image]

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. Instead copy the text direct into the question: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/5014688).

Answer (score 2):

You're using python 3 but installed the module for python 2

Use `sudo pip3 install flask-ask` to install it for python 3